# Python multiprocessing iterable leads to wrong index in range()

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing, range

I am trying to write a python code that plots the number density of a list of numbers, showing how many numbers in the input reside within which interval of the number line. In the input "states.dat" file, I have

```
3.5
3.6
```

and the script I wrote

```
import numpy as np
import re
import multiprocessing as mp


cpu_read=open('density.pbs', "r")
for line in cpu_read:
    if re.search("select", line):
        cpu = int(re.split('=|:',line)[5])
        print("total number of cpu used for parallelization:", cpu)


step = 0.1
start = 3.5
end = 4.50

states = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('states.dat')]
states_array=np.array(states).astype(np.float)

nsteps = int((end - start) / step)
print("nsteps\n", nsteps)

final = np.zeros((nsteps+1 ,2), dtype=float)

for i in range (nsteps+1):
    final[(i,0)] = start + i*step


def final_DOS(i):
    print("iteration",i)
    final[(i,1)] = np.count_nonzero((states_array >= final[(i,0)]) & (states_array < final[(i+1,0)]))
    return final[(i,1)]

#for i in range(nsteps):
#   final_DOS(i)

pool = mp.Pool(cpu)
pool.map(final_DOS(i),[i for i in range (nsteps)])
pool.close()
pool.join()


print("completed final array\n", final)

np.savetxt('DOS.txt',final,fmt='%5.5f', delimiter='    ')

print("done!")
```

is able to give me the correct output when I do not use multiprocessing, i.e. with the

```
pool = mp.Pool(cpu)
pool.map(final_DOS(i),[i for i in range (nsteps)])
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

commented off and

```
#for i in range(nsteps):
#   final_DOS(i)
```

uncommented. This will give the output

```
total number of cpu used for parallelization: 2
states_array
 [3.5 3.6]
nsteps
 10
iteration 0
iteration 1
iteration 2
iteration 3
iteration 4
iteration 5
iteration 6
iteration 7
iteration 8
iteration 9
completed final array
 [[3.5 1. ]
 [3.6 1. ]
 [3.7 0. ]
 [3.8 0. ]
 [3.9 0. ]
 [4.  0. ]
 [4.1 0. ]
 [4.2 0. ]
 [4.3 0. ]
 [4.4 0. ]
 [4.5 0. ]]
done!
```

However, when I run the script with the multiprocessing turned on, as what is presented in the full code here, I get the following output and error message:

```
total number of cpu used for parallelization: 24
nsteps
 10000
tail: density.out: file truncated
total number of cpu used for parallelization: 2
states_array
 [3.5 3.6]
nsteps
 10
final array
 [[3.5 0. ]
 [3.6 0. ]
 [3.7 0. ]
 [3.8 0. ]
 [3.9 0. ]
 [4.  0. ]
 [4.1 0. ]
 [4.2 0. ]
 [4.3 0. ]
 [4.4 0. ]
 [4.5 0. ]]
iteration 10
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "density.py", line 41, in <module>
    pool.map(final_DOS(i),[i for i in range (nsteps)])
  File "density.py", line 34, in final_DOS
    final[(i,1)] = np.count_nonzero((states_array >= final[(i,0)]) & (states_array < final[(i+1,0)]))
IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11
```

I don't understand why the multiprocessing will end up getting i=10 in a range (nsteps) that maxes out at 9 when multiprocessing is turned on. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the small point that you do not close your file (use a `context manager` for that).

```
with open('density.pbs', "r") as cpu_read:
    # your parsing

# Now the file is closed here.
```

You are not passing a function to the `map` parameter, but tell the function `final_DOS` to run with the value `i`. Which was used here:

```
for i in range(nsteps + 1):
    final[(i, 0)] = start + i * step
```

And the final answer is 10, therefore `i` is defined as 10, when you hit the following line:

```
pool.map(final_DOS(i), [i for i in range(nsteps)])
```

You will increase `i` once more, in the `final_DOS` function leading to 11.

To use the map method, note that you have to pass in the function, uninitialized. In any case `final_DOS` (note that there are no brackets.)